# How to correctly concatenate strings in shells script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, string

I have a bash shell which I need to modify, and I have to set a variable in a script and then call another script. My variable, `EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS` must be

```
-javaagent:myagent.jar="-d 0 -i 1000 -l log2 -c log1"
```

So what I did is

```
export EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS="-javaagent:myagent.jar=\"-d 0 -i 1000 -l log2 -c log1 \""
```

Then I call my script and inside my script there is the following :

```
"$JAVACMD" "$EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS"
```

However, this won't produce the result I desire. Running bash -x I can see that

```
+ /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/java '-javaagent:myagent.jar="-d 0 -i 1000 -l log2 -c log1"'
```

If on the contrary I do:

```
"$JAVACMD" $EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS
```

I got a different version of the output, which is wrong too

```
+ /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/java '-javaagent:myagent.jar="-d' 0 -i 1000 -l log2 -c 'log1"'
```

How do I prevent `'` from appearing when printing my strings, or them to be added by the shell?

Comment: Weird.  What does `"$JAVACMD $EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS"` do? Or just plain no quotes at all?

Comment: Did you mean to pass a single argument to `java` containing among others two `"` characters? You show several things that go wrong, but what is your desired result (making sure to distinguish between any quoting that you're using for presentation, and quotes and whitespace that must end up in an argument passed to `java`)?

Answer (score 3):

The quotes are just to prevent splitting by word. But you already have quotes around the whole thing.

```
export EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS="-javaagent:myagent.jar=-d 0 -i 1000 -l log2 -c log1"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using an array is a safe way to keep your arguments containing whitespace intact:

```
EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS=(-javaagent:myagent.jar="-d 0 -i 1000 -l log2 -c log1")
"$JAVACMD" "${EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS[@]}"
```